# displaying html lists in a tree-like row-like fashion

Tags: html, css

I have a list

```
<ul>
 <li> first article </li>
 <li> second article</li>
 <ul>
    <li> replies to second</li>
    <li> different reply to second</li>
 </ul>
 <li> third article</li>
 <ul>
    <li> reply to third</li>
    <ul>
        <li> reply to the reply</li>
    </ul>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Which begets something like

- first article
- second article

  - replies to second
  - different reply to second
- third article

  - reply to third
  - reply3
  - reply3

    - reply to the reply

What i'm trying to achieve is basically make every inner level it's own row:

```
 [first article]
 [second article]
 [rep2]   [difrep2]
 [third article]
 [reply3] [reply3] [reply3]
 [^3reply to the reply]
```

The problem is: when I put a box around list elements, the box contains the parent and all the descendent/inner elements.  I want a box around the list element, and I would like the children to appear on a new "row"

Is there any way to "kick" the inner list elements out of their parent's css box so that they appear on a new "row" ?

https://jsfiddle.net/qjf6tsf8/1/

^Update: please check out this fiddle.

In the fiddle "yet another child" has children elements, and I'd like to put them in a new row *below* "yet another child" instead of recursively boxing them up.

For reference: https://jsfiddle.net/qjf6tsf8/ (js fiddle showing the tree structure with just li and ul elements, and then the upper link I've changed them to divs)

[image: desired effect for list-to-rowtree]

Comment: What CSS have you already tried? Have you got a JSFiddle with an example that we can see? My first thoughts would be to target the specific elements at the right levels (e.g. `ul > li > ul > li` for the "row" elements) and then make them `display: inline block` to let them sit next to one another. It's a bit hard to help without seeing any other markup/CSS, though. Please could you add what you've already tried.

Comment: @GeoffJames thanks Geoff, I added a JSFiddle to illustrate the issue I'm coming across: the boxes recursively box up child elements and i'd like to make a new row for child elements.  I'm using angular so i'll be able to make certain rows click-to-show-and-hide but i'm stuck on this fundamental CSS issue of how to kick the child elements "out of the list" and "into a new row"

Comment: Is this what you look for?... https://jsfiddle.net/qjf6tsf8/3/

Answer (score 1):

First off, according to [W3C HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), any `<ul>` cannot be the direct child of a `<ul>`.

So this structure

```
<ul>
  <li> first article </li>
  <li> second article</li>
  <ul>
    <li> replies to second</li>
    <li> different reply to second</li>
  </ul>
...
```

Should actually be

```
<ul>
  <li> first article </li>
  <li> second article
    <ul>
      <li> replies to second</li>
      <li> different reply to second</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
...
```

This actually makes your issue less difficult to resolve.
**See https://jsfiddle.net/tae2e7ea/.**

The important part is below. Use `display: block` to put the child `<ul>` on its own line, then `display: inline-block` for the `<li>` children.

```
/* <ul> that are children of <li> should be on their own line */
li > ul {
  display: block;
}

/* And the children of those <ul> should be all on one line */
li > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Edit for additional info: See the fiddle for some additional styles you may need to set on the `<li>` (like `vertical-align: center`) or `<ul>` (like `padding-left: 0`)

Edit after clarifications from asker: Since 100% width is desired and this control is being handled with JavaScript (AngularJS), I recommend organizing by levels in the tree instead of maintaining the tree-like structure you started with. See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tae2e7ea/1/) for that update. JavaScript can then be used to show/hide the necessary levels. Or rather, AngularJS should be used to only render the lists for the "chosen" level.

Comment: Really a quality answer!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and approach.  Please check out the added image.  The issue I'm trying to get at is to no longer nest the boxes but actually create a new row with inner DOM elements.  Think it's possible?

Comment: @sova: Your posted [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVseT.png) seems to want all the rows to be 100% width. Is this the case? If so, you're starting to get into the realm of Flexbox. It may still be possible, but you may not have the [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) you want without some JS help. How will you handle the case where E2 also has children? Will this become a tabbed layout where E1's children become hidden? That changes the question completely.

Comment: @AndrewMessier yes, I want all the rows to have 100% width.  It will be a tabbed layout because I can control which rows are displayed on clicks with angularjs.  As a start I think it will be good to try and get every row to show up, and then later selectively hide the non-active ones.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's possible with the given HTML setup you have. Because each list is contained in its parent, the list won't be able to take up the full 100% width of the top list items. Instead, I recommend this approach, where you organize by level, instead of using a tree structure: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tae2e7ea/1/). This should still be easy to implement in AngularJS. You can hide the lists that don't apply to the selected item in the level above.

Comment: @AndrewMessier thanks Andrew.  I was trying to short-cut with a recursive template (recursive ng-include), but since that creates a dom-tree / nested-tree i'll have to find another way of including new levels dynamically

Comment: @sova no problem. You may want to update your question with the AngularJS tag and the clarifications from your last comments, or create a new question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work

```
ul >  ul 
{
 display : inline-flex ; 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Andreas my english is bad add for me :)

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi people will not edit / write your answers for you (unless to fix syntax / errors). Make sure to [edit] and improve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not decided to display items correctly yet. Because you have think of levels differently in a way that can not be common for all levels. For clarity pay attention to item `replies to second`. What if it had some children?! You can add a class name like **.same-row** to every item you want to be displayed in a same row and add fallowing style to your page:

```
.same-row{
    display: inline;
}
```